# DEPRECATION WARNING: How to remove "WARNING:calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ with constraint is deprecated..."

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I'm getting this warning and can't figure out how to remove it.

This is the full warning,

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\gener\anaconda3\envs\freq\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
2021-01-25 16:10:27.289896: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\gener\anaconda3\envs\freq\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_impl.py:183: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
```

Here is the code.

```
import tensorflow
import crepe
from scipy.io import wavfile
import csv
import numpy as np
    
def get_freq(filename):
    outputDict = {}
    
    sr, audio = wavfile.read(filename)
    time, frequency, confidence, activation = crepe.predict(audio, sr, viterbi=True, step_size = 10)

    for stamp in time:
        index = np.where(time == stamp)[0][0]
        outputDict[stamp] = frequency[index]

    with open("../csv/output.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["time", "freq"])
        for stamp in outputDict:
            writer.writerow([stamp, outputDict[stamp]])
    print("Done get_freq.")
```

My tensorflow is 2.4.0 and I tried putting tf.where in place of np.where but that just made my code stop working. The first warning Im not sure what it even means. I saw online that these error are harmless to the code, but their difficult to code with, so if there is a way to get rid of them it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The warning is telling you what to do. In any case, you could look at the according code that generates the warning and check the version control system to get further insight when and why it was written.

Comment: I followed the instructions but then mu code stopped working.

Comment: I've seen that these warning can ussually be ignored, is there a way to stop them from showing up altogether.

Comment: Well, it might be beneficial if people here had enough info to reproduce the warning. Also, if you "fixed" it and then it stopped working, you didn't fix it. Again, nobody knows what exactly you did. Consider  providing something like a [mcve]. Also, read [ask] again.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not a good idea to ignore warnings but it seems like maintainers of tensorflow are using them a bit more than community likes (check the number of dislikes on this contributor's comment - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27023#issuecomment-475684266)

To disable them it seems like this might work:

When using tensorflow 2.X, you can use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

And when using tensorflow 1.X:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

Taken from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27023#issuecomment-589673539

Comment: A warning message came up and told me to use this instead "tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)", and it worked.